# Сравнить переменные в объектах JAVA

Tags: java, сортировка

Существуют шесть объектов - кубов у которых есть объем(сторона задана в ручную). Как мне отсортировать объемы кубов и вывести информацию в табличном виде что-то вроде

- имя   объем сторона
- куб2   100л     3
- куб1   90л      2
- куб3   80л      4

Comment: В чем проблема? С сортировкой? Выводом?

Comment: С выводом. Я создал 6 объектов(кубов). Присвоил им значение "а", вычислил их объем. Потом создал массив и поместил туда значения объема от каждого объекта. Отсортировал с помощью "пузырька". Но когда дело дошло до вывода, я понял что могу вывести только объем, а соответствующие значения переменной "а" вывести не могу

Comment: Возможно есть другой способ выполнить задачу, без использования массивов. Надо создать в ручную 6 кубиков, вычислить их объем и отсортировать объемы. Потом вывести полную информацию в табличном виде (не только объем но и сторону)

Comment: Перепишите пузырек для Куба, а еще лучше сделайте его generic-ом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Отсортировать список можно при помощи метода статического `Collections.sort()`. При этом класс должен реализовывать интерфейс `Comparable`
- Вывести можно при помощи метода `System.out.println()`
- Отформатировать вывод можно переопределив метод `toString()`

```java
class Cube implements Comparable<Cube>;
  private final String name;
  private final int edge;

  public Cube(String name, int edge) {
    this.name = name;
    this.edge = edge;
  }

  private int getVolume() {
    return edge * edge * edge;
  }

  @Override
  public int compareTo(Cube obj) {
    return Integer.compare(getVolume(), obj.getVolume());
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return String.format("%s %d %d", name, getVolume(), edge);
  }
}

List<Cube> list = new ArrayList<Cube>;
list.add(new Cube("cube1", 5));
list.add(new Cube("cube2", 7));
list.add(new Cube("cube3", 3));
Collections.sort(list);
for (Cube cube : list)
  System.out.println(cube);
```